# How to read and deserialize IEnumerable of objects with httpclient

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a problem with reading and deserializing the HTTP response from my simple web API that supposes to return IEnumerable of ContactDto object. In `contentReader.Read()` line I'm getting an error as:

> "Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1."

Controller get code:

```
    [HttpGet]
    // GET api/<controller>
    public IEnumerable<ContactDto> Get()
    {
        return new List<ContactDto>()
        {
            new ContactDto()
            {
                DateOfBirth = DateTime.Today,
                FirstName = "tmp",
                LastName = "tmp"
            }
        };
    }
```

Model code:

```
public class ContactDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}
```

Reading and parsing with HttpClient:

```
public IEnumerable<ContactDto> Read()
{
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ContactDto));

        var client =new HttpClient();

        var stream = client.GetStreamAsync(_feedUrl).Result;

            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                using (var contentReader = new XmlTextReader(streamReader))
                {
                    while (contentReader.Read())
                    {
                        var innerEventXml = contentReader.ReadAsString();
                        using (var stringReader = new StringReader(innerEventXml))
                        {
                            yield return (ContactDto) serializer.Deserialize(stringReader);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: What's your receive data content from your api?

Comment: You're probably receiving JSON, not XML.

Comment: code update, I'm using simply new HttpClient(). So everything is probably set by default

Comment: @D-Shih What do You mean, how can i check data? I suppose it is stream of data

Comment: @CodeCaster Where should I change it? on web api site or client site?

Comment: Inspect the received data and determine its format. Then either change your deserialization code, or change your request headers.

Comment: @CodeCaster it looks like content type of received data is application/json; charset=utf-8

Comment: Returning a list in an Action gives a JSON result, not XML ^^ Give us an example of the data so that we can help you.

Comment: @Haytam when I changed GetStreamAsync to GetStringAsync I received something like this :"[{\"Id\":0,\"FirstName\":\"tmp\",\"LastName\":\"tmp\",\"DateOfBirth\":\"2018-08-06T00:00:00+02:00\"}]"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Returning a list of objects in your `Get` action results in a JSON result when calling it, not a XML result.

You can deserialize it using [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) for example:

```
string result = client.GetStringAsync().Result;
return JsonConvert.Deserialize<List<ContactDto>>(result);
```

Althought I would suggest you to use `await` for the async methods.